Integral over triangle - change of variables
Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ $$f(x)=\frac12-\left|\frac12-x\right|.$$
Evaluate the integral $$\int_Dxy\,d(x,y)$$ using the change of variables
\begin{align}
x&=u(1-v),\\y&=uv,
\end{align}
$u\in(0,\infty)$, $v\in(0,1)$.
my attempt: We have to use the change of variables formula. Therefore, define the coordinate transform $g\colon\widetilde{D}\to D$ with $g(u,v)=(u(1-v),uv)$. By supposing
$$g(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}u(1-v)\\uv\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
I try to determine $\widetilde{D}$. I get $v=\frac yu$ and so $$x=u(1-v)=u(1-\frac yu)=u-y\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad u=x+y$$
Consequently, $v=\frac{y}{x+y}$. Clearly, $u\in(0,1)$ but what happens to $v$, as $x+y$ gets arbitray small? Any suggestions on how to continue?

Yeah, $D={(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in(0,1),0<y<f(x)=\frac12-|\frac12-x|}$

If we let $\widetilde{D} = { (u,v) | g(u,v) \in D }$, then a bit of work shows that $\widetilde{D} =[0,1] \times [0, {1 \over 2}]$. One approach might be to consider $\widetilde{D}_n =[{1 \over n},1] \times [0, {1 \over 2}]$ and take limits (with justification, of course).

@copper.hat If we write $D={0\le y\le 1/2, y\le x\le 1-y}$, from $y\le x \le 1-y$, we get $2y\le u \le 1$, so $u\in[0,1]$. Since $2y=2uv$, then $0\le v\le \frac 12$. Do you think this method is correct?

@SineoftheTime I'm not sure what you mean by correct, are you trying to derive the inverse image?

@copper.hat I'm trying to find the bounds for the new variables and I was asking if the procedure is ok, if you don't mind taking a look at it

@SineoftheTime My own attempt is not quite correct, I have the closure of the area. I think your approach needs more work to establish equivalence.

@SineoftheTime yep, your approach will work, took me a while to see it.

@copper.hat Thank you for feedback :)

You can express $D$ in the following way: $D=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y\le x \le 1-y, 0\le y \le 1/2\}$. From $y\le x\le 1-y$, adding $y$ you get $2y\le u\le1$. Since $y\ge 0$, $u$ varies between $0$ and $1$. Moreover, $y=uv$ so $0\le2uv\le u \le 1$. From $2uv\le u$ you get $v\le1/2$ (the other inequality does not add informations). At the end, your new domain is:
$$\widetilde D=\left\{(u,v)\in \Bbb R^2: 0\le u \le 1, 0 \le v \le \frac 12\right\}=[0,1] \times [0,1/2] $$
